# store information in one struct to another

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct, and I'm trying to read a file into a struct, and then make changes to that file and store it into another struct. Not sure what to do, new to c programming.

So far I have this:

----this struct below is where i read the files into

```
struct salesperson_in

{

     int salesnum ;
     char lastname[20] ;
     char firstname[20];
     int saleslevel;
     double salesamount;
     double salespay;
};
```

---- i want to use this struct to store my changes in.

```
struct salesperson

{

     int salesnum;
     char lastname[20];
     char firstname[20];
     int saleslevel;
     double salesamount;
     double salespay;

};
```

---- my attempt to take whats in the first struct, and put in the second
( outrec in this case is number 2 above, and inrec is where i read the files into)

```
    outrec[i].salesnum = inrec[i].salesnum;
    outrec[i].lastname[] = inrec[i].lastname[];
    outrec[i].firstname[] = inrec[i].firstname[];
    outrec[i].saleslevel = inrec[i].saleslevel;
    outrec[i].salesamount = inrec[i].salesamount;
```

Comment: Do you mind asking any question !

Comment: Maybe you could explain a little more what your problem is? As @KaustavRay points out, this site works better with clear questions.

Answer (score 0):

take in count that for string copy use the function strcpy of the string library. The to copy a struct is using memcpy . A struct is a description of a memory zone, the way to locate resources. When you need to clone that memory zone you need to reserve the space require for that struct definition and copy fron one memory address to another. Search a little more for memcpy.